# How can I confirm an assumption of an automatically inferenced type at compile time? (i.e. static_assert style

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time, static-assert

Occasionally, I'll assign the returned value of a function to a variable of `auto` type (e.g. `auto returnValue = someFunction();`), but ***still*** would like to clarify/enforce certain assumptions about the type of that variable - i.e. That it is of type `int`.

While Concepts & type_traits provide some very powerful static assumption-verifying features, they don't enable something like this:

```
static_assert( isType( returnValue, int ) );
//OR
static_assert( int == typeof( returnValue ) );
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use type traits ie [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) here :

```
static_assert( std::is_same<int, decltype( returnValue ) >:: value  ,  "Error, Bad Type");
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/Zx4ixX).

Comment: correct, I thought he wanted to check the returned value

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
int fn1()
{
    return 0;
}

long fn2()
{
    return 0;
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto r1 = fn1();
    static_assert( std::is_same<int, decltype(r1)>::value, "Bad type" ); // OK

    auto r2 = fn2();
    static_assert( std::is_same<int, decltype(r2)>::value, "Bad type" ); // FAILED assertion
}
```